# CakePHP 3.0 / DebugKit Plugin Element Override

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-debug-kit

I am trying to override the template file for the environment panel in the CakePHP 3.0 DebugKit.  The file is located at

**app/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Template/Element/environment_panel.ctp**

According to the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-templates-from-inside-your-application), placing my own file at

**app/src/Template/Plugin/cakephp/debug_kit/Element/environment_panel.ctp**

should automagically display my template instead of the plugin's, however, my file is being ignored.  I've tried leaving out the cakephp directory, and using camel case for the vendor/plugin names.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After two more hours of experimentation I found the correct path:

**app/src/Template/Plugin/DebugKit/Element/environment_panel.ctp**

To clarify the confusion I had: the debug kit is not considered a composer/vendor-type plugin mentioned in the docs I linked in the question, so it doesn't need the **../cakephp/..** intermediate directory.

Additionally, the directory needed to be CamelCased instead of copied verbatim from the vendor directories.

ALSO: in apparent conflict with the Element docs, you CAN override a plugin element without setting the `['plugin' => false]` option.